# What typeface is used for County Boroughs on OS 6" to Mile Maps?

Tags: cartography, font, historical-maps

I came across this wonderful typeface on an OS 6" to Mile map (from [National Library of Scotland](http://maps.nls.uk/projects/subscription-api/)):

[image]

By perusing the [Characteristics Sheet](https://maps.nls.uk/view/128076894) it looks like it is representing a county borough (or country burgh in Scotland).

Does anyone know what the typeface is? and is it available to download anywhere? Or do I need to work out the minimal number of boroughs to get a full alphabet?

Comment: Unless you want to recreate historic maps, from a cartographical POV I'd advise against using this or similar fonts, since they are harder to read. Otherwise... I don't know, sorry. Though I associate it rather with the US Midwest than Scotland.

Comment: There is some good information from the Charles Close Society on O.S. Fonts https://www.charlesclosesociety.org/files/Issue108page2.pdf  (Seems to be a mixture and older maps were type-setted individually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting

Comment: And you can always find free typeface files on sites like this https://www.1001freefonts.com .  The 'retro' category returned 722 styles.  Of course, you can always create the style yourself  https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating-custom-fonts.html